# Why is it that Deku didn't fully give Kachan One For All in the movie "Boku no hero Academia: Heros Rising"?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I was watching the movie and in the final battle against Nine, all looks lost for Deku and Bakugo until Deku offers to give *One For All* to Bakugo. Everything works out and they defeat Nine. When All Might is holding Deku in his arms after the battle, Deku lets All Might know that he gave Bakugo *One For All*. After that Deku passes out his *Full Cowling* stripes (I couldn't think of a better word to describe them) show up. All Might is relieved by this. He says (and this isn't a quote) that he (Midoriya) didn't fully transfer *One for All* to Bakugo. I was wondering why this was and how it's going to affect the plot of the story.

(I assumed at firsts it was for plot armor but I am starting to second guess it. They would have made Deku go "Super Saiyan" and beat Nine by himself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as impact on the overall story goes there will be none whatsoever. Anime movies made alongside an ongoing series being adapted from a manga are almost always entirely separate from the established canon and are original stores, therefore they are unable to make any lasting changes.

In universe All Might himself refers to Deku retaining One For All after the battle as a "Miracle" speculating that whatever remains of the previous holders within One For All didn't fully transfer the quirk to Bakugo, this could be seen as somewhat similar to how One For All wasn't inadvertently transferred to Stain despite him consuming some of Deku's blood.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. You do have a point with the fact that it was a miracle.

Comment: I don't think the fact that One for All didn't accidentally transfer to Stain is a useful point, while its established O4A transfers via DNA All Might also establishes that it also only transfers when its wielder willingly gives it up. Otherwise, Deku wouldn't be the 9th user but likely the 9000th as All Might would've lost it the first time he kissed someone or volunteered at a soup kitchen and a hair fell in the soup.

Comment: That's exactly why I mentioned it, it's an example that's actually canon showing it doesn't have to change hands every time there's some sort of contact.

Comment: It still seems completely unrelated to both the question and answer. The fact that O4A only transfers with its wielder's permission is an understood aspect of the quirk, the aspect in question is how after Deku willingly gives O4A up does it come back to him. The fact that the quirk doesn't randomly transfer doesn't matter given Deku very explicitly gives it to Bakugo. Evidence that would support this would be an instance of O4A being shared/lent out (probably not a thing), you could however build a case using the previous wielders who give Deku extra powers that were not a thing before him

Answer (score 0):

I do not disagree with [IG_42's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/65884/19307) and think it correct, but I would like to add to it a bit since I just watched this movie.

### What the Movie Says

During the movie, All Might gives a partial explanation to what happened. Here is the quote:

> Young Bakugo must've lost consciousness before the transfer finished. No, that's not it. For risking your life to protect. And for risking your life to prevail. All For One did something **miraculous**. Master and all of those who came before... thank you so much. I'm forever grateful.

In short, it was a miracle, just as IG_42's answer said.

There's also something akin to an explanation that Midoriya says. It doesn't really explain anything, but I'll include it anyway (Apologies, this one might not be the exact quote, but should be close enough).

> Kacchan didn't remember about the transfer of All For One to him afterwards. And **somehow** the power remained with me.

So basically Midoriya's explanation is "I dunno."

Establishing it as a "miracle" is actually very convenient, because it means

1. It does not need to be fully explained.
2. We should not expect it to happen again. In other words, this is an anime movie where the writers are playing it loose with the rules of the established story, and we shouldn't expect the rules herein to carry over to the main story in the manga and anime.

### Interpretation

So it was a miracle and needs no explanation. I'm going to explain it anyway (or try, at least).

First, we should examine the first thing All Might said. At first he suspects that Bakugo lost consciousness before the transfer finished. That's odd, actually. It tells us something about how the transference of All For One works. It means it doesn't simply complete immediately after the current holder transfers the power via an infusion of their DNA (at least according to All Might's understanding). Rather, the process of transferring from one user to the next continues even after that until it complete. It seems kind of strange to think of it like that, but that's what the story is saying.

Second, we should look at Bakugo's intentions. In his dialogue, he expressed concern that Midoriya would permanently lose his power. This shows that Bakugo probably did not intend to keep All For One, and would have given it back to Midoriya if he were given a choice.

Third, we look at the will of All For One. The vestiges of the past users living inside All For One would seem to have a will of their own. All Might even expresses in the quote that it was their intention to share the power with Bakugo, but to stay with Midoriya.

I suspect these three reasons are why Midoriya retained All For One. Namely, there was still a connection between him and Bakugo through All For One, and both Bakugo and the vestiges willed the power return to Midoriya.

### Other Examples

As a side note, this isn't the first time something like this has happened in an anime movie. Go check out the first Broly movie in the *Dragon Ball* franchise, where they win the day by all giving their energy to Goku. Not sure how canonical being able to do that was at the time, but they did something like that when creating the Super Saiyan God, so I guess it's canonical *now*.

Further examples: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CombinedEnergyAttack and https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnergyDonation.